# How to make an efficient query which depends on two arrays in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

The main problem that mongodb does not allow to create index on two fields when each of it holds an array:

`{a:[1,2], b: [8,9]}`

And because of that I'm experiencing difficult times trying to solve the next problem.

**Collection description**

Collection name: items

- Each item can belong to many (thousands) of folders
- Each item could be read by many (thousands) of users.

**Current collection structure (simplified)**

```
folderDataArr: [{
    _id: 1,
    dateOfAddingIntoFolder: 01.01.11
}, {
    _id: 2,
    dateOfAddingIntoFolder: 01.01.12
}],
userDataArr: [{
    _id: 100,
    isRead: true,
    dateOfRead: 01.0.10

}, {
    _id: 101,
    isRead: true,
    dateOfRead: 01.02.31


}]
```

**Query to build**

I need to reformat my structure to make an efficient query:

- return last N items which belong to some folders and which was NOT read by specific user. AND the result should be sorted by date when that news were added to a folder (in other words by "dateOfAddingIntoFolder" field).

**The question is**

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what are the quantities that you are talking about here? how many items per folder, how many folders and how many users do you expect for this dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to restructure your collection in your mongodb. Since you are include the new entity "news item" and your final output is news item which is unread. I suggest following way. Before that, I have done visualize your data as follows

```
usercollection
- user (email id, last logged in time)

NewsCollection
- newsitem (newsid,newsdata,createdtimestamp,updatedtimestamp)
```

Whenever changes in news item like create,update then change createdtimestamp,updatedtimestamp
respectively

If user logged in, pick old logged-in timestamp(before update current) and choose all the news item which is having greater than old logged-in timestamp in either createdtimestamp or updatedtimestamp.

**Note**: Since News Item and User are independent entity keep them in a single collection is not advisable.

**Note*****: Since User and News are having many-to-many relationship, trying to give high user specific news update need more number of document update or you have to manipulate more elements in array for each news/user related changes. If you are trying to do this, think about your app performance.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: you seem to have forgot about folders entirely - the whole idea is that each item belongs to possibly many folders and that for each user you want to only show items from certain folders which are unread.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky, Here user and newsitem are dynamic data content, why do we store them folder/file system?

Comment: because that's part of requirements - read the original question.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky, Lets wait [@Dmitry Rogov] reply

Comment: I should agree with Asya. Each requirement is very important - including belonging items (news) to different folders.

Comment: @Dmitry Rogov, Then I need answer for [@Asya Kamsky]'s question to get more insight about your systems architecture. And couple of questions below 1. In which parameter, you are naming folder or categorize news item? 2. "Each item can belong to many (thousands) of folders", So do you allow duplication of news item?